# Как можно время на сервере сделать локальным?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, хостинг

Раньше у меня хостинг бы в Москве, в моей временной зоне, и сайт работал как ожидалось. Сейчас переезжаем на новый хостинг (SmarterAsp, Shared) у которого время смещено на несколько часов.

Можно ли как-то настроить DateTime.Now что бы возвращал Московское время, или надо переписывать код?

Если переписывать, то думаю что пройдусь заменой по `DateTime.Now` -> `DateTime.LocalNow` , где `LocalNow` будет мой extension.
Как тогда лучше организовать работу этой функции?

Вот мой код, прошу проверить правильность работы

```
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Moscow Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, tz);
```

для ускорения `tz` вынесу в статическую константу.

Правильно ли я понимаю что `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` приводит местное локальное время в любую Time зону? Отчего вопрос. Потому что мне непонятно из какой зоны эта функция работает, ведь при конвертации зоны нужно знать зону A (откуда конвертировать) и B (куда конвертировать) и тогда сделать расчёт. И не очень понимаю как без знания A это сделать, или A это временная зона сервера?

Как вообще на сайтах обычно делают привязку к часовому поясу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получаем все временные зоны

```
foreach (TimeZoneInfo zoneID in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine(zoneID.Id + "<br/>");
}
```

Конвертируем время

```
protected DateTime GetCurrentTime()
{
     DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now;
     DateTime _localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(serverTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Russian Standard Time");
     return _localTime;
}
```

Пример взят отсюда: https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1697/how-to-convert-server-time-zone-to-local-timezone-using-_net.aspx

Comment: Этот пример видел, но не обратил внимание на `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(serverTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Moscow Standard Time")`, а тут как раз есть и A и B, спасибо, теперь понятно. Просто этот пример для старого ASP.NET, а это уже давняя технология, я подумал что может что-то изменилось с того времени.

Comment: Надо делать "Russian Standard Time", "Moscow Standard Time" такого нет. Я поправил в ответе.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин благодарю, Moscow взял из вашего вопроса

Comment: ну так я и просил код проверить )) эта часть была нерабочей